# About "polyptoton"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, repetition

I am struggling with these phrase and sentences. Please translate in plain English or can you make it easy to understand.

1) Thank me no thankings, nor proud me no prouds.

2) Tut, tut!
   Grace me no grace, nor uncle me no uncle:
   I am no traitor's uncle; and that word "grace"
   In an ungracious mouth is but profane.

Comment: Sorry, I made misspel for traitor's uncle.

Comment: 1. "You’re not really giving me any thanks or showing me any pride." (see [No Fear Shakespeare](http://nfs.sparknotes.com/romeojuliet/page_198.html).

Comment: 2. "Don't talk to me about grace, or call me your uncle: I disown you, traitor, and think that you talking about grace, when you neither know what grace is, nor have any of your own, is wicked."

Comment: You can [edit] your post by clicking on the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They just mean "Do not thank me"; "Do not be (or say) proud in front of me"; "Do not say 'grace' to me"; Do not say "uncle" to me".

They mostly involve words or meanings of words that do not exist except in a poetic phrase like this: *uncle* and *proud* are not normally verbs, for example.